# Wordpress: List All Pages/Posts with Specific URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a php script or wordpress plugin, where I can type in a specific url and get a list of all pages or posts that have that url in their content as links?

Answer (score 0):

Get all posts, then filter the ones that have the link you're looking for in their content.

```
$all_posts = get_posts(['numberposts'=>-1]);
$posts = array_filter($all_posts, function($post) {
   return strpos('https://example.com/', $post->post_content) !== FALSE;
});
```